# Nestjs common repo dependency in conflicts with Project repo dependency

Tags: nestjs, package.json, monorepo

I'm working with a home grown mono repo structure in with NestJS and legacy code. The NestJS parts of the monorepo depend on a common folder in the root that is imported into each Nest Project via `"commonPackage":"file:../common"` in the `package.json` file.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the common folders install of `@nestjs/config` is conflicting with the consuming project's install of the same package. I've been using a workaround to import the necessary code from `commonPackage/node_modules/@nestjs/config` however that is using the common folder's `.env` file instead of the consuming project's `.env`

I have no runtime dependencies in the common package, and I've set `@nestjs/config` as a peer dependency with a version flag of `^1` however, when attempting to import the consuming project's config
(i.e. `import {ConfigService} from '@nestjs/config';` and not the above) service I get an error about an internal property not matching in the spec like below.

```
 src/app.module.ts:16:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(config: ConfigService) => ConnectionOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '(config: ConfigService<Record<string, unknown>>) => ConnectionOptions'.
   Types of parameters 'config' and 'config' are incompatible.
   Type 'ConfigService<Record<string, unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'ConfigService<Record<string, unknown>, false>'.
   Types have separate declarations of a private property 'internalConfig'.

     16     MysqlModule.register(sqlConfig),
                                 ~~~~~~~~~
[3:47:23 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: Any update on the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround solution I worked out was to simply export the config service I was using for my internal module, however I now think it should be possible to pass in the config service when registering the module.

so My current solution is to export the config service from the module that uses it in the common repo:

```
export declare type SpecConfig = ConfigService;
```

Use this when defining factories that get put into that module.

*** One caveat is that you will not be able to specify a custom config file with this method as the import is handled in your register logic.***

another option is to add the config service as a dependency to the module registration, but I have yet to work that out.

for example this is my Dynamic Module that was causing the issue.

```
import { DynamicModule, Module, Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as mysql from 'mysql2';
import { MysqlConnectionService } from './mysql-connection/mysql-connection.service';


@Module({})
export class MysqlModule {
    static register(...options: MysqlModuleOptions[]): DynamicModule {
        const providers: Provider<any>[] = options.map(({config: connectionConfig, name}) =>   {
            const config = {
                provide: `${name}-mysql-config`,
                useFactory: connectionConfig,
                inject: [ConfigService]
            }
            const provider = {
                provide: `${name}-mysql`,
                useFactory: (config: mysql.ConnectionOptions) => new MysqlConnectionService(config),
                inject: [`${name}-mysql-config`],
            }
            return [config, provider];
        }).reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
        return {
            module: MysqlModule,
            imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true})],
            providers: [...providers],
            exports: [...providers]
        }
    }
}

export type MysqlConfigFunc = (config: ConfigService) => mysql.ConnectionOptions
export type MsqlConfigService = ConfigService;

export class MysqlModuleOptions {
    name: string;
    config: MysqlConfigFunc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option here is to use a workspace manager that keeps all dependencies in a repo in check and in line with each other. the purpose of the common project is to provide a location where shared logic can live. a workspace manager like [NX](https://nx.dev) handles the hard work of this for you. it's a little work getting it started, but it's well worth the headache.